# Lag in emulator and genymotion when closing/starting new activities ( eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented )

Tags: android, performance, android-emulator, genymotion

So I have this problem where both genymotion & intel haxm emulator lag when opening and closing new activities (even when pressing home)
For example when I close the stock messaging app I get this in the logs(while runing the HAXM emulator):

```
12-02 21:05:48.950    1304-1336/system_process I/ActivityManager﹕ START u0     {act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.HOME] flg=0x10200000 cmp=com.android.launcher/com.android.launcher2.Launcher} from uid 1000 on display 0
12-02 21:05:48.960     948-1684/? E/gralloc_goldfish﹕ gralloc_alloc: Mismatched usage flags: 576 x    576, usage 333
12-02 21:05:48.960     948-1684/? W/GraphicBufferAllocator﹕ alloc(576, 576, 1, 00000333, ...) failed -22 (Invalid argument)
12-02 21:05:48.960     948-1684/? E/﹕ GraphicBufferAlloc::createGraphicBuffer(w=576, h=576) failed (Invalid argument), handle=0x0
12-02 21:05:48.960    1304-1336/system_process E/BufferQueueProducer﹕ [ScreenshotClient] dequeueBuffer: createGraphicBuffer failed
12-02 21:05:48.960    1304-1336/system_process W/WindowManager﹕ Screenshot failure taking screenshot for (1080x1920) to layer 21015
12-02 21:05:48.960    1304-1336/system_process E/ActivityManager﹕ Invalid thumbnail dimensions: 576x576
12-02 21:05:49.010    1629-1748/com.android.launcher W/EGL_emulation﹕ eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
12-02 21:05:49.010    1629-1748/com.android.launcher W/OpenGLRenderer﹕ Failed to set EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR on surface 0x7fc24ca8c800, error=EGL_SUCCESS
12-02 21:05:49.870    1629-1748/com.android.launcher W/OpenGLRenderer﹕ Incorrectly called buildLayer on View: ShortcutAndWidgetContainer, destroying layer...
12-02 21:05:49.870    1629-1748/com.android.launcher W/OpenGLRenderer﹕ Incorrectly called buildLayer on View: ShortcutAndWidgetContainer, destroying layer...
12-02 21:05:49.870    1629-1748/com.android.launcher W/OpenGLRenderer﹕ Incorrectly called buildLayer on View: ShortcutAndWidgetContainer, destroying layer...
```

Do you guys have any ideas how to fix that?

PC: Windows 8.1 64bit, 9800GT, i5 3570, 16GB RAM

Comment: Add more cpu core to your virtual device could help. Both for HAXM and Genymotion.

Comment: I'm sorry for a silly question, but what exactly did you mean by "add more cpu core"? Would you clarify please? I'm having this exact problem on one of my PCs, the funny thing is it's the fastest one.